# Angular promise from ActivatedRoute doesn't work with Typescript await

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

To access components in the current URL path, the following works in my application:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
...
load() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      const id = +params['id'];
      console.log('got parameter', id);
 ... etc
```

This is the textbook case and the variable **id** gets set as advertised.  But I want to use the more elegant **await** form and it doesn't work.  (Of course I will have a string of **await** statements following.)  Like this:

```
async load() {
    try {
      console.log('getting parameters');
      const params = await this.route.params.toPromise();
      console.log('got params', params);
      const id = +params['id'];
  ... etc
```

What I get is the output from the first **console.log()** call but the second never comes.  And of course the **id** variable doesn't get set and the rest of the code never executes.

The documentation and the working code says that **this.route.params** is an **Observable**, which should be convertable to a **Promise** via **toPromise()** and thereby used with Typescript **async**/**await**.  I use **await** statements with the **Observables** that come out of the **HttpClient** module just fine.

But it doesn't work.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The basic answer is: **You are having incontrollable race conditions here**

When you access the Observable `route.params` it's pretty normal that it isn't completed yet. Calling `toPromise()` on it at this point in time will lead to an enduringly pending Promise and this is the problem you are facing.

If you are not bound to using this async await construct leave it and better directly access synchronously `params.id` via ActivatedRouteSnapshot.

```
ngOnInit() {
    const id: string = route.snapshot.params.id;
}
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem or answered your question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes that worked but what I don't get is why the examples I was following was using the Observables form and led me so far astray.  On top of that I don't understand why the ActivatedRoute uses Observables in the first place.  Why wouldn't the route and the URL be settled and.or static at the time the component is instantiated?   Oh, well I will research that later.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I want the large answer, I need a explication for what reason I cant transform a Observable in a Promise.

Answer (score 4):

Apropos AlanObject's question *... why the ActivatedRoute uses Observables in the first place ...*, the reason is the `ngOnInit()` is called only on component initiation, that is, when it is created. Imagine your component is used to display item details with a route like `/item/123`, where `123` is the current item `ID`.

Now, if your component would implement also a *Previous* and *Next* links navigating to `/item/122` and `/item/124`, the component would not be instantiated again. In such cases you would need a subscription or another way to get the `ID` and related data updated.